# How can I open Outlook PST files read-only in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

Running Outlook 2010 on Windows 7

I have two quite large outlook files each about 700MB each. I need regularly to access the emails in them, they are archives from recent years. However each time I open them, the date (and maybe something internally in the file) gets updated, this means that my backup software tries to back them up again during an incremental backup. I would like to open the PST files read-only (and of course for indexing searching too) so that the dates and the files are not changed. I don't really want to exclude them from backups, as I would like them in the full backup.

If I set the file to be read-only on the filesystem then outlook refuses to open it.

So to summarize the question again. How can I force outlook 2010 to open some PST files read only so they are available for reading, indexing and searching, but don't get changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming Outlook 2010 has similar architecture to Outlook 2007.  My source is specific to Outlook 2007 and lower, but I doubt anything has changed.

You cannot, by design.  Indexing, reading, and searching write to the PST file.

Source: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269520

From the article:

> There are three reasons why Outlook does not support opening personal
>   folders (.pst) files on read-only media (such as, CD-ROMs) or
>   read-only folders:
>
> The .pst file is a database file format. As the user navigates through
>   the Outlook user interface, the user expects the computer to respond
>   with searches and sorts (similar to when a user clicks a view column
>   header to sort the content in the view). The computer must be able to
>   write to the .pst file so that those search and sort procedures are
>   available.
>
> The user expects to be able to change the view contents, for instance
>   the user may want to add columns, and the user may want Outlook to
>   remember the current sort order, filters, and so on. The view
>   definition saves the information into a special area in that Outlook
>   folder, therefore the view definition is written to the .pst file.
>
> The .pst file is in a single-user file format. The computer uses a
>   special area of the file to write information about the computer that
>   opened the file. The file allows other processes on the same computer
>   to access the file while it prevents other computers from accessing
>   the file until the first computer closes the file. Without this "file
>   lock" feature, the computer is open to file damage when two computers
>   open the .pst file at the same time.
>
> These design decisions reflect the core architecture of Outlook and
>   Messaging Application Programming Interface (MAPI).

Comment: ...now if we could simply get MS to acknowledge that there is more than one use case here and allow us to open the PST read-only and then not allow all of *those* cool features while allowing the one read-only feature that we do want.